# PostgreSql or SQL Server 2008 R2 should be use with .Net application using entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework, postgresql, entity-framework-4, ado.net, postgresql-9.0

I have a database in PostgreSQL with millions of records and I have to develop a website that will use this database using Entity Framework (using dotnetConnect for PostgreSQL driver in case of PostgreSQL database).

Since SQL Server and .Net are both native to the Windows platform, should I migrate the database from PostgreSQL to SQL Server 2008 R2 for performance reasons?

I have read some blogs comparing the two RDBMS' but I am still confused about which system I should use.

Comment: Stay with Postgres. I don't think that "compatibility" with .Net will have a big impact.

Comment: Time to benchmark.  But yeah I see no great reason to migrate to SQL server.  Unless you have a pile of cash just laying about.

Comment: Most of the performance issues that you encounter will be more likely due to the use of EF and not the database backend.

Comment: @swasheck: that's why i asked this question because i'll use EF, so which DB should i use.

Comment: @JitendraPancholi my point is that EF may be a performance issue regardless of which RDBMS you use.

Answer (score 1):

There is no clear answer here, as its subjective, however this is what I would consider:

- The overhead of learning a new DBMS and its tools.
- The SQL dialects each RDBMS uses and if you are using that dialect currently.
- The cost (monetary and time) required to migrate from PostgreSQL to another RDBMS
- Do you or your client have an ongoing budget for the new RDBMS? If not, don't make the mistake of developing an application to use a RDBMS that will never see the light of day.

Personally if your current database is working well I wouldn't change. Why fix what isn't broke?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out if there is actually a problem, and if moving to SQL Server will fix it before doing any application changes.

Start by ignoring the fact you've got .net and using entity framework.  Look at the queries that your web application is going to make, and try them directly against the database.  See if its returning the information quick enough.

Only if, after you've tuned indexes etc. you can't make the answers come back in a time you're happy with should you decide the database is a problem.  At that point it makes sense to try the same tests against a SQL Server database, but don't just assume SQL Server is going to be faster.   You might find out that neither can do what you need, and you need to use faster disks or more memory etc.

The mechanism you're using to talk to a database (DotConnect or Microsoft drivers) will likely be a very minor performance consideration, considering the amount of information flowing (SQL statements in one direction and result sets in the other) is going to be almost identical for both technologies.